# Cache do banco de dados não está sendo armazenado pelo SpringBoot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Estou tentando armazenar o cache de uma busca do banco de dados feita através do JPA, para isso estou usando a anotação `@Cacheable` do package `org.springframework.cache.annotation` em cima do método `getPerfisPermitidos()` que está na minha `@Entity` **Usuario**

```
@Cacheable
public List<Perfil> getPerfisPermitidos() {
    return perfisPermitidos;
}
```

Eu também já coloquei a anotation `@EnableCaching` dentro da classe inicial do SpringBoot

```
//importações

@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = "xx.xxx.xxxxx.xx", 
        exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class }
)
@EnableCaching
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    //implementação
}
```

porém quando eu realizo a seguinte busca:

```
List<Perfil> perfisDoUsuario = usuarioRepository.findById(username).get().getPerfisPermitidos();
List<Perfil> perfisDoUsuario2 = usuarioRepository.findById(username).get().getPerfisPermitidos();
List<Perfil> perfisDoUsuario3 = usuarioRepository.findById(username).get().getPerfisPermitidos();
```

O **Hibernate** faz 3 buscas no banco ao invés de fazer somente a 1° e as outras 2 ficarem em cache.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        usuario0_.email as email1_14_0_,
        usuario0_.nome as nome2_14_0_,
        usuario0_.sobrenome as sobrenom3_14_0_,
        perfisperm1_.email as email2_15_1_,
        perfil2_.perfil as perfil1_15_1_,
        perfil2_.perfil as perfil1_9_2_,
        perfil2_.descricao as descrica2_9_2_ 
    from
        Usuario usuario0_ 
    left outer join
        UsuarioPerfil perfisperm1_ 
            on usuario0_.email=perfisperm1_.email 
    left outer join
        Perfil perfil2_ 
            on perfisperm1_.perfil=perfil2_.perfil 
    where
        usuario0_.email=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        usuario0_.email as email1_14_0_,
        usuario0_.nome as nome2_14_0_,
        usuario0_.sobrenome as sobrenom3_14_0_,
        perfisperm1_.email as email2_15_1_,
        perfil2_.perfil as perfil1_15_1_,
        perfil2_.perfil as perfil1_9_2_,
        perfil2_.descricao as descrica2_9_2_ 
    from
        Usuario usuario0_ 
    left outer join
        UsuarioPerfil perfisperm1_ 
            on usuario0_.email=perfisperm1_.email 
    left outer join
        Perfil perfil2_ 
            on perfisperm1_.perfil=perfil2_.perfil 
    where
        usuario0_.email=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        usuario0_.email as email1_14_0_,
        usuario0_.nome as nome2_14_0_,
        usuario0_.sobrenome as sobrenom3_14_0_,
        perfisperm1_.email as email2_15_1_,
        perfil2_.perfil as perfil1_15_1_,
        perfil2_.perfil as perfil1_9_2_,
        perfil2_.descricao as descrica2_9_2_ 
    from
        Usuario usuario0_ 
    left outer join
        UsuarioPerfil perfisperm1_ 
            on usuario0_.email=perfisperm1_.email 
    left outer join
        Perfil perfil2_ 
            on perfisperm1_.perfil=perfil2_.perfil 
    where
        usuario0_.email=?
```

Comment: Na realidade você está fazendo errado, você está buscando `usuario` e não `perfis`. Sua instrução de cache deve ser feita na `usuarioRepository.findById` e não no getter da classe usuário. De qualquer forma, caso não queira deixar o usuário inteiro em cache, você deve customizar sua área de cache por entidade (utilizando configs do ehcache por exemplo)

Comment: Olá @nullptr você teria algum link de uma possível implementação que eu possa me basear para seguir em meu projeto, ou documentação em especifico? pois o problema que eu noto é que o meu UsuarioRepository herda de uma Interface chamada BaseRepository, e esta por sua vez herda de JpaRepository, também existe um BaseRepositoryImpl que extends SimpleJpaRepository e também implementa BaseRepository... O que eu quero dizer com isso é que não está adiantando ir na interface UsuarioRepository e colocar o `@Cacheable` pois ele não está cacheando o usuário.

Comment: O tutorial e a documentação do Spring são muito bons, da uma olhada [aqui](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) e [aqui](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html)

Comment: conseguiu ajustar seu cache ou ainda precisa de ajuda?

Comment: sim está funcionando parcialmente, ele já está cacheando no ambiente local, porém está dando erro no deploy para o AppEngine. Assim que eu conseguir resolver esse bug volto aqui para postar a solução completa do problema, alias sua dica foi preciosíssima, bastou eu reescrever a query na classe que herdava de SimpleJPARepository e ele começou a cachear.

Comment: Ótimo :) Fico feliz em ajudar